# Camel route, how to use an Endpoint as a trigger, returning an immediate response but continuing with the process?

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, routes, multicast, endpoint

I want to use Camel to implement a kind of trigger EIP.

What I want is this:
I have a web service that will act as a camel-route endpoint. This service receives a request and if the request is well-formed it must do two things in parallel:
return a response to the original sender with a simple message "OK" or "ACK" or in case of the request not being well-formed the response will be "NOK" or "RPT" (asking to repeat the message).
then at the same time, if the message is well-formed it must be sent to another web-service that will enrich the original message with some info and send the resulting Message (or Exchange, I'm not sure of the right term here) to a JMS implementation.

My endpoint acts as the trigger for a process but must return a response right away to the caller.

So my question is, what component can I use to do this? I'm implementing the route with Spring DSL.
I started by using:

```
<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:clientEventEip?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
  <multicast>
    <to uri="bean:messageResponse"/><!-- checks the message and returns 'OK' -->
    <to uri="bean:messageEnricher"/><!-- Enriches and sends msg to another WS -->
  </multicast>
</route>
```

But I'm getting an error response in the client:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and in the IDE a lot of exceptions like:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException
```

and

```
 org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.w3c.dom.Document but has value: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@b8c6fb of type: null on: Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: null to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@b8c6fb due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.. Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: null to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@b8c6fb due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
```

If I just use one of the beans in my camel route all goes well, the response is the one I expect.

I'm sure that it's my mistake, I must be using the wrong component but I still haven't figured out how so solve this, I appreciate any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the Wiretap pattern that Camel offers:

http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html

The wiretap essentially takes a copy of your exchange and route asynchronously to a different endpoint.  The link above has more detail.

You could check your message and if it is okay, you could call both a wiretap endpoint and your response endpoint.  Something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:clientEventEip?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>

    <wireTap uri="direct:tap"/>      

    <to uri="bean:messageResponse"/><!-- checks the message and returns 'OK' or 'NOK'-->

</route>

<route>
   <from uri="direct:enrichingRoute"/>
   <to uri="bean:messageEnricher"/><!-- Enriches and sends msg to another WS -->
</route>
```

You will probably need to add a filter to check for errors prior to calling the wiretap but I think the wireTap EIP should point you in the right direction.

Cheers,
Yogesh